# get child category along with child category group name

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, mysqli

Table : category

[image: cat]

Table : category_child_title

[image: title]

Table : category_child

[image]

Expected outputs is like this

[image]

---

I tried sofar

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE is_deleted = 0";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $categories = $query->result_array();

        foreach($categories as $key => $category)
        {
            $cat_id = $category['id'];

//          $sql = "SELECT child.name as childName, group_concat(title.name)  as titleName
//                  FROM category_child AS child
//                  LEFT JOIN category_child_title AS title on child.fk_category_child_title = title.id
//                  WHERE child.fk_category = $cat_id  AND  child.is_deleted = 0
//              ";
//
            $sql = "SELECT name, fk_category_child_title FROM category_child WHERE fk_category = $cat_id  AND  is_deleted = 0";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            $categoryChild = $query->result_array();

            $categories[$key][] = array( 'childs' => $categoryChild);
        }
```

Outputs is

[image]

any helps please

Comment: The data structure seems a little odd. Surely category_child_title should have a foreign key to category, and then category_child should have a foreign key to category_child_title. Then you've got a clear and simple hierarchy

Comment: @ADyson `category_child` own foreign key of category its `fk_category` and  `fk_category_child_title` is foreign key of `category_child_title`

Comment: yes I can see that but I'm saying it doesn't look like the best structure because it doesn't directly reflect the hierarchy of menu items you're trying to produce. It would almost certainly be simpler to code with a 3-layer hierarchy. Just a suggestion.

Comment: your database structure is not good, but you want to continue with this then use join query like

`SELECT fc.name, fc.fk_category_child_title,c.name as child_title FROM category_child as fc left join category_child_title as c on c.id=fc.fk_category_child_title WHERE fc.fk_category = $cat_id  AND  fc.is_deleted = 0`